Event horizon transcript
http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/e/event-horizon-script-transcript-neill.html
Event Horizon transcript:
Want something hot and black?

Is that an offer?

No.


What does he mean exactly with this phrase “Is that an offer?”

Remember, one question per post. Please [edit] down and make it clear what the question is. (Formatting hint: there's a quote tool in the bar at the top of the question-edit window)

Could you add a few details for clarity: 1) Who was speaking 2) What is the time signature of the video at the time of the quote. 3) Which version of the video are you referring to as IMDB lists 4 films and 1 TV show called "Event Horizon".

Remember external links go down and shouldn't be relied on - questions should be self-contained and have all the information included necessary to find an answer. Please state explicitly the exact film you're referring to, the characters speaking, and the point in the dialogue the exchange happens (by time signature or page number).

The line (from Event Horizon [1997] @11m50s) is actually, "would you like something hot and black inside you" {your transcript is wrong}
This is a double enterdre meaning that Cooper is both offering Starck

A cup of coffee, or
Offering to have sex with her.

She fobs him off with a rude gesture indicating a firm "No!".

Compare this to the script...

          Cooper, still butt-naked and proud of it, grabs a metal 
          cylinder from the wall and pours a mug for himself.

                               COOPER
                   Hey, Starck. You wanna dry my back?

          Starck gives him a cool once over.

                               STARCK
                   Maybe when you finish puberty.


